# Same front-end action triggers different events?

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer

On the front-end, a user can save his account information (name, address, etc.). Let's call this action `user-save`.

I'm finding that when the user doesn't have any address information, `user-save` triggers the `customer_save_after` event. The observer then provides a `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` object, which lacks address information, understandably.

If he has at least one address saved, `user-save` triggers `customer_address_save_after`. Then the observer provides a `Mage_Customer_Model_Address` object, which has all of the user info.

Am I getting this right? Why is this?

UPDATE:
Actually it looks like when a customer has addresses in his account, `customer_address_save_after` is triggered in addition to `customer_save_after`, once for each address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*_save_after` event is triggered for each model that extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` when calling the `save` method.
When saving a customer the addresses associated to it are saved also, that's why the `customer_address_save_after` is dispatched.
This is don from `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer::_saveAddresses()` that is called from `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer::_afterSave()`